# Invariant under the choice basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $H$ be a full rank $m \times n$ matrix with $m<n$ and $A$ is any invertible $n \times n$ matrix. Consider the subspace $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:Hx=0\}$; It is well-known that this subspace has dimension $n-m$. For a given basis $\cal B$ of $S$, define a matrix $K$ by $K=[K_1,\ldots,K_{n-m}]$ where $K_1,\ldots,K_{n-m}\in \cal B$.
I'd like to prove that the matrix $K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA$ is independent with the choice of the basis $\cal B$.
I only can see when $A$ is identity matrix . But, if no, I haven't no idea. Is there any suggestion? Thanks...

Comment: Certainly in the square case it follows from $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1}X^{-1}$ and $(X^T)^{-1} = (X^{-1})^T$. I don't know about non-square matrices...

Comment: Thanks @BenMillwood, but $K$ is definitely singular.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S'=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \left<s,Ax\right> = 0 \text{ for all }s\in S \}$. Then $S'$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and it's clear $\dim(S')=m$. Indeed, $S' \equiv A^{-1}(S^{\perp})$, and $\dim(S^{\perp})=m$.

Now consider the matrix $M=K(K^T A K)^{-1} K^T A$. Observe that $M$ has the following two properties:

(1) $M$ is the identity when restricted to $S$, since $MK=K$.

(2) $M=0$ when restricted to the subspace $S'$.

But there is exactly one such linear mapping with these two properties, and these two properties depend only on $S$ and $A$, i.e., they are independent of the choice of $K$. Thus, $M$ is independent of the choice of $K$.

Comment: Just curious -- did you ever take a look at this lovely answer I wrote?

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I've just read your answer. Thanks for your help Will

Comment: Jlamprong, This answer has 0 upvotes nor is it marked correct. That makes me think that perhaps you didn't understand the answer? Let me know if you have any question about it. It's actually a very nice type of argument that I first saw for orthogonal projection matrices, which are VERY useful in a variety of domains, e.g., optimization and statistics (particularly regression).